# an exponent problem

Tags: exponential-function, exponentiation

I need the value of $x$, but I cannot figure out how to deal with ${\sqrt x-1}$ in the following equation.

> $x^{\sqrt x-1} =3/2$

Could anyone please help me to figure this out.

Comment: You need numerical methods (or perhaps the Lambert-W-function can be used)

Comment: @Peter I'm not familiar with numerical method. My mathematics knowledge is of elementary level. Could you please suggest something a elementary student should know?

Answer (score 2):

x=9/4 is a solution

$\sqrt(9/4)=3/2$

$3/2-1=1/2$

$9/4^{\sqrt(9/4)-1}=\sqrt(9/4)=3/2$

Comment: Have you calculated it backwards?

Comment: It was kind of obvious.

Comment: Because you're a genius. But I am having a really hard time to understand how it works.

Comment: I was lucky and from practice but if something seems hard is because there might be some "lucky" idea behind. Next one will be easier to find.

Answer (score 1):

Let's substitute, $x=y^2$,

$$
x^{\sqrt{x}-1}=(y^2)^{y-1} = y^{2y-2} = \frac{3}{2}
$$

$$
\implies y^{y-1} = \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}
$$

This is still an implicit equation but we got rid of the $\sqrt{x}$.

Here is the [Numerical Solution by Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%5E%7By-1%7D%20%3D%20%5Csqrt%7B%5Cfrac%7B3%7D%7B2%7D%7D). This problem cannot be solved analytically using elementary operations. You need to follow some algorithm like [Bisection Method][2]. They work by taking some initial interval at the start say $[1, 100]$. Check the function value at both points. Then bisect the current interval i.e. check the value at $y=50$. We see that the root lies in $[1, 50]$. This way we go on bisecting the interval to get to the solution.

The solution using any of the algorithms is $x=0.3616$ or  $x=2.25$.

[2]: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithms#:~:text=The%20simplest%20root%2Dfinding%20algorithm,point%20that%20bisects%20the%20interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithms#:%7E:text=The%20simplest%20root%2Dfinding%20algorithm,point%20that%20bisects%20the%20interval)).

Comment: Sorry, I should have been a little more specific in my question. I need the value of $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider that you are looking for the zero's of function
$$f(x)=x^{\sqrt x-1} -\frac 32$$
Its derivatives are
$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{2} x^{\sqrt{x}-2} \left(2 \sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x} \log (x)-2\right)$$
$$f''(x)=\frac{1}{4} x^{\sqrt{x}-3} \left(4 \left(x-2 \sqrt{x}+2\right)+\log (x)
   \left(4 x-5 \sqrt{x}+x \log (x)\right)\right)$$

The first derivative cancels at $x=1$ and $f(1)=-\frac{1}{2}$, $f''(1)=1$. So, this point is a minimum and there are two solutions
$$0 < x_1 < 1 \quad 1 < x_2$$

Build a Taylor series around $x=1$. It will be
$$-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2} (x-1)^2+O\left((x-1)^3\right)$$ This gives two solutions : $0$ and $2$ and $0$ must be discarded.

$$f(2)=2^{\sqrt{2}-1}-\frac{3}{2}\sim -0.167428 \implies x_2 >2$$ and you were already told that $x=\frac 94$ is the largest solution. Then, I shall not focus on this one.

Adding one more term to the expansion, we have
$$-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2} (x-1)^2-\frac{3}{8} (x-1)^3+O\left((x-1)^4\right)$$ which is a cubic in $(x-1)$. The discriminant being negative $(\Delta=-\frac{179}{256})$, there is only one real root. Using the hyperbolic method, we have
$$\frac{1}{9} \left(13-8 \cosh \left(\frac{1}{3} \cosh
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{211}{32}\right)\right)\right)\sim 0.207953$$

So, now we have our starting guess for Newton method. For the smallest root, the iterates are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 0.207953 \\
 1 & 0.291319 \\
 2 & 0.346314 \\
 3 & 0.360882 \\
 4 & 0.361632 \\
 5 & 0.361634
\end{array}
\right)$$

This number is not recognized by inverse symbolic calculators, but (given for the fun) it is close to
$$\frac{11+\sqrt{23}}{50}\, \sqrt[3]{\frac{3}{2}}  \sim   0.361634266$$ while the "exact" solution is $0.361634272$.

Even if this does not mean any thing, for this funny number $f(x)=1.56\times 10^{-8}$.

Answer (score 0):

I performed an iterative solution with an Android phone simulator of an HP-$42$S. I started by taking the log of both sides.
$$x^{\sqrt{x}-1}=\frac{3}{2}$$
$$(\sqrt{x}-1)\cdot\log(x)=\log\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)$$
$$\sqrt{x}-1=\frac{\log\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)}{\log(x)}$$
$$\sqrt{x}=\frac{\log\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)}{\log(x)}+1$$
$$x=\left(\frac{\log\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)}{\log(x)}+1\right)^2$$
Start with an initial value of $x=5$ and watch a solution evolve.

After coding the below, plug in 5, and XEG "SME".
The HP-$42$S code follows:
LBL "SME"
STO 01
LBL 01
3
2
/
LOG
RCL 01
LOG
/
1
+
X^2
STO 01
VIEW ST X
PSE
GTO 01

This is at least one solution there may be others.

The simulator is so fast, if you take the PSE out, you will just see a solution. For example, incrementing X from 0 to 1,000,000 takes seconds.